# Python: How do I fit a line to a specific interval of data?

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize

I am trying to fit a line to the 9.0 to 10.0 um regime of my data set. Here is my plot: [image]

Unfortunately, it's a scatter plot with the `x` values not being indexed from small numbers to large numbers so I can't just apply the `optimize.curve_fit` function to a specific range of indices to get the desired range in `x` values.

Below is my go-to procedure for curve fitting. How would I modify it to only get a fit for the 9.0 to 10.0 um `x`-value range (in my case, the `x_dist` variable) which has points scattered randomly throughout the indices?

```
    def func(x,a,b):                                # Define your fitting function
    return a*x+b                                  
  
initialguess = [-14.0, 0.05]                     # initial guess for the parameters of the function func

fit, covariance = optimize.curve_fit(             # call to the fitting routine curve_fit.  Returns optimal values of the fit parameters, and their estimated variance
        func,                                     # function to fit
        x_dist,                                    # data for independant variable
        xdiff_norm,                                    # data for dependant variable
        initialguess,                             # initial guess of fit parameters
        )                                     # uncertainty in dependant variable

print("linear coefficient:",fit[0],"+-",np.sqrt(covariance[0][0])) #print value and one std deviation of first fit parameter
print("offset coefficient:",fit[1],"+-",np.sqrt(covariance[1][1]))     #print value and one std deviation of second fit parameter

print(covariance)
```

Comment: What is your input? A numpy array? Do you know the index or do you know the value range to which you want to limit the fit? If the former, then `curve_fit(func, x_dist[start:stop], xdiff_norm[start:stop], ...` will suffice.

Comment: @Mr.T it is a numpy array. my issue is if I call a range of indices, it will not correspond to a range in my x values. Say if I pick [200:250], the 50 indices im calling on will have xvalues scattered randomly throughout my entire range, which isn't much help. One idea I have is to order the indices from smallest xvalue to largest xvalue, then I can call on a specific index range.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You correctly identified that the problem arises because your x-value data are not ordered. You can address this problem differently. One way is to use Boolean masks to filter out the unwanted values. I tried to be as close as possible to your example:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize

#fake data generation
np.random.seed(1234)
arr = np.linspace(0, 15, 100).reshape(2, 50)
arr[1, :] = np.random.random(50)
arr[1, 20:45] += 2 * arr[0, 20:45] -5
rng = np.random.default_rng()
rng.shuffle(arr, axis = 1)
x_dist = arr[0, :]
xdiff_norm = arr[1, :]

def func(x, a, b):                              
    return a * x + b      

initialguess = [5, 3]
mask = (x_dist>2.5) & (x_dist<6.6)
fit, covariance = optimize.curve_fit(           
        func,                                     
        x_dist[mask],   
        xdiff_norm[mask],    
        initialguess)   

plt.scatter(x_dist, xdiff_norm, label="data")
x_fit = np.linspace(x_dist[mask].min(), x_dist[mask].max(), 100)
y_fit = func(x_fit, *fit)
plt.plot(x_fit, y_fit, c="red", label="fit")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Sample output:
[image: ![enter image description here]

This approach does not modify `x_dist` and `xdiff_norm` which might or might not be a good thing for further data evaluation. If you wanted to use a line plot instead of a scatter plot, it might be rather useful to sort your arrays in advance (try a line plot with the above method to see why):

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize

#fake data generation
np.random.seed(1234)
arr = np.linspace(0, 15, 100).reshape(2, 50)
arr[1, :] = np.random.random(50)
arr[1, 20:45] += 2 * arr[0, 20:45] -5
rng = np.random.default_rng()
rng.shuffle(arr, axis = 1)
x_dist = arr[0, :]
xdiff_norm = arr[1, :]

def func(x, a, b):                              
    return a * x + b      

#find indexes of a sorted x_dist array, then sort both arrays based on this index
ind = x_dist.argsort()
x_dist = x_dist[ind]
xdiff_norm = xdiff_norm[ind]

#identify index where linear range starts for normal array indexing
start = np.argmax(x_dist>2.5)
stop = np.argmax(x_dist>6.6)

initialguess = [5, 3]
fit, covariance = optimize.curve_fit(           
        func,                                     
        x_dist[start:stop],   
        xdiff_norm[start:stop],    
        initialguess)   

plt.plot(x_dist, xdiff_norm, label="data")
x_fit = np.linspace(x_dist[start], x_dist[stop], 100)
y_fit = func(x_fit, *fit)
plt.plot(x_fit, y_fit, c="red", ls="--", label="fit")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Sample output (unsurprisingly not much different):
[image: ![enter image description here]